# How to select a template for a custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I've created a custom post type and custom taxonomy (all fine so far!) but when I try to view the post it's giving me a page not found.

What do I need to do to setup a template which the custom post type below will use?

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
function create_post_type() {
    register_post_type( 'members',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Members' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Members' )
            ),
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'supports' => array('title','editor','comments'),   
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'members' ),
        )
    );
}

function members_init() {
    // create a new taxonomy    
    register_taxonomy(
        'members',
        'members',
        array(
            'label' => __( 'Member Categories' ),
            'sort' => true,
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'args' => array( 'orderby' => 'term_order' ),
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'members' )
        )
    );  

}
add_action( 'init', 'members_init' );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the WordPress [template hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy), a custom post type 'my-cpt' will first try to use `single-my-cpt`, then `single.php` and then `index.php`. The above issue is not caused by templates - indeed 404s are used when the content, not the template, cannot be found.

You are using a custom rewrite:

```
'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'members' )
```

For WordPress to recognise this you'll need to flush your rewrite rules by visiting the Settings > Permalink page.

Comment: Thanks, flushing the permalinks (I always forget to do that!!) worked. So if I create a template called single-members.php that should work? It's now showing a template just not sure what one!

Comment: If you create `single-members.php` it will use that, if not it will use `single.php`. In the unlikely case that doesn't exist either it will use `index.php`.